# Tomcat catalina.log catches many exceptions

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have faced application slowness issue and it throws java exception 'failed to connect to database'.
Which i investigated initially that it came from a catch block whose try block is solely do the database connectivity and runs some query.
I still do not know what the issue was. I also looked into the catalina.log file of tomcat, where i got several issues.
These is issues may not be related with application slowness but those are many issues there.
I am listing down all the issues reported in catalina.log, so that you can help me.Many thanks in advance..

### > catalina.log

```
xxxx-xx-xx xx:49:21,311 ERROR main org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina - Catalina.start: 
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use:xxxx
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409)

xxxx-xx-xx xx:49:21,312 ERROR main org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer - StandardServer.await: create[19331]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:346)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:600)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:560)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409)

xxxx-xx-xx xx:49:21,313 ERROR Thread-1 org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector - Protocol handler pause failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkMain.pause(JkMain.java:675)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.pause(JkCoyoteHandler.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:629)

xxxx-xx-xx xx:49:21,571 ERROR main org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use:xxxx
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.initEndpoint(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:297)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:509)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:408)

xxxx-xx-xx xx:49:22,319 WARN Thread-1 org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener - Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:629)
```

Answer (score 1):

"ERROR main org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol - Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use:xxxx"

Iguess that you are trying to start tomcat in a port that is already in use. try to use netstat to find which application is using this port (XXXX).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will check that definitely. but what about the other errors? What about 'org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector - Protocol handler pause failed
java.lang.NullPointerException' ? Can you please help ? thanks in advance

Comment: probably this error is related to the above one. Please checks that keep happening once fixed the first one.